# How can I modify my code in order to avoid duplicate entries in this generator function?

Tags: python, generator

The problem is as follows: Write a function choose_gen(S, k) that produces a generator that yields all the k-element subsets of a set S (represented as a sorted list of values without duplicates) in some arbitrary order.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def choose_gen(l: object, k: object) -> object:
    if k>len(l):
        return None
    elif k == len(l):
        yield sorted(l)
        return
    for i in l:
        aux = l[:]
        aux.remove(i)
        result = choose_gen(aux, k)
        if result:
                yield from result
```

It runs but does not avoid the duplicate subsets. Could somebody please help to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

an example of an input would be:

```
print([s for s in choose_gen([1,3,5,7], 2)])

actual output: [[5, 7], [3, 7], [3, 5], [5, 7], [1, 7], [1, 5], [3, 7], [1, 7], [1, 3], [3, 5], [1, 5], [1, 3]]

expected output: [[5, 7], [3, 7], [3, 5], [1, 7], [1, 5], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: You should provide example input and the expected output

Comment: I may be missing something here but can you explain why the second parameter with a value of 3 results in pairs of values? Also, what happens if *k > len(l)* ?

Comment: Hi, the second parameter, should be a 2, that was a typo. Additionally, if k > len(l), I can just set it to return None (I have changed the code to reflect this.)

Comment: Maybe looking into [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) implementation of `itertools.permutations` helps to deal with the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But

I think that in the 6th line you have to write something after return. You have left it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Or try,

```
new_menu = [s for s in choose_gen([1,3,5,7], (2)]

final_new_menu = list(dict.fromkeys(new_menu)) 

print(final_new_menu)
```